# How to debug ToolStrip error "'child' is not a child control of this parent"?

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I've created a custom ToolStrip control and ToolStripControl control so that I can fully customise all the parts of them primarily the hover event, however I'm getting an issue in the Designer where it throws this error:

> 'child' is not a child control of this parent

Here is my code for when the control is added

```
private void ToolStripPro_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    if (!CheckType(e.Control.GetType(), typeof(ToolStripProControl)))
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(e.Control);
    }

    Invalidate();
}
```

And my `CheckType` function referenced above

```
private bool CheckType(Type check, Type checkType)
{
    if (check == checkType)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (check.BaseType != null)
        {
            return CheckType(check.BaseType, checkType);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the class declaration for the `ToolStripPro` control

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))] 
public partial class ToolStripPro : UserControl
```

I think everything else is just whats built into VisualStudio and the designer. I might be wrong but this should give an idea of my situation.

Comment: It's best to add code that _you_ feel is relevant, since as the question stands it doesn't have anything to go on, and may be put on hold in due course.

Comment: @halfer Just added some code which is the most relevant